# Emoticons em sistema de postagens

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Tenho um sistema de postagens no meu site, porém são pouquíssimas opções para a 'personalização' da postagem pelo utilizador. Então gostaria de inserir a opção que o usário insira emoticons nas postagens.

Quando me refiro a inserir emoticons, estou me referindo ao usuário por símbolos no campo de postagem e ao postar esses símbolos virarem emoticons.

Como faço para inseri-lo em meu script? Gostaria de um passo a passo de como fazer isso.

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nesse tópico do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658734/a-better-way-to-replace-emoticons-in-php) e [esse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907286/php-for-loop-str-replace-emoticons)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar [esse plugin](https://github.com/JangoSteve/jQuery-CSSEmoticons) muito simples de implementar
Ele funciona assim:

```js
$('.comment').emoticonize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://os.alfajango.com/css/jquery.cssemoticons.css">
        <script src="https://os.alfajango.com/js/jquery.cssemoticons.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment">
            Hi, this is a great plugin! :-)
        </div>
```